# How do I upload multiple excel files to multiple FTP folders using python or VB?

Tags: excel, ftp

I am needing to move about 40 excel spreadsheets to various folders on the FTP site(DAILY) based on excel file name.

For example if File1.xls  then it will be moved to a directory's folder A
            if File2.xls  then it will be moved to a directory's folder B
and so forth.

So there are 40 files and 40 directories.  Can someone please help me automate this in Python or VB?

I appreciate your help,
Jaimi

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `ftplib`. Here is some untested code to get you started:

```
import ftplib

files = (
    # list your files and dirs here
    ('local_file1.xls', 'target_dir1'),
    ('local_file2.xls', 'target_dir2'),
    # etc.
)
ftp = ftplib.FTP("ftp://example.com")
ftp.login()
for filename, directory in files:
    f = open(f, 'rb')
    ftp.cwd(directory)
    ftp.storbinary("STOR %s"%filename, f)
    ftp.cwd('..')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am getting the following error: "TypeError: Coercing to Unicode: Need string or Buffer, Tuple found"

Comment: It's difficult to answer without more information. Can you post your code and the full error?

Comment: from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP(www.ftp.com)  # connect to host, default port

directory = ('ATNET')

files = (
    ('1121_Score_Card.xls', '/ATNET/ls0931/FROMLS'),
    ('1122_Score_Card.xls', '/ATNET/ls1674/FROMLS'),
    ('1123_Score_Card.xls', '/ATNET/ls5738/FROMLS'),
    ('1124_Score_Card.xls', '/ATNET/ls1476/FROMLS')
        )

for filename, directory in files:
    f = open(files, 'rb')
    ftp.cwd(directory)
    ftp.storbinary("STOR %s"%filename, files)
    ftp.cwd('..')
    files.close()


#ftp.quit()

Answer (score 1):

in VB.net try the following (it works in vb 2008):

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("localfilename", "ftp server address", "username", "password")
```

Hope it helps and works (BTW , its my first time here so sorry if I did anything wrong)

Comment: if its a form then either in form_load button_click,     
if its a console then just plonk it in the main sub